# ionic erro ao usar o plugin socialSharing

Tags: apache-cordova, ionic3, npm, cordova-plugin

Estou tentando usar o plugin [socialSharing](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/social-sharing/), segui todas as etapas desse [tutorial](https://medium.com/@mikeyny/easy-social-sharing-with-ionic-3-and-ionic-native-f2c42807f43c) mas quando pressiono o botão liga a função compartilhar eu recebo o erro:

> 'object is not a function at socialShare.share()'

Já verifiquei e os arquivos do plugin estão lá:

meu ionic info:

```
Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)  : 4.10.1 (/usr/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2
   @ionic/app-scripts : 3.2.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : android 7.0.0, browser 5.0.4
   Cordova Plugins       : cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2, cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4, (and 10 other plugins)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/opt/SDK)
   NodeJS            : v11.8.0 (/usr/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.5.0
   OS                : Linux 4.15
```

meus plugins do cordova:

```
cordova-plugin-device 2.0.2 "Device"
cordova-plugin-device-motion 2.0.1 "Device Motion"
cordova-plugin-geolocation 4.0.1 "Geolocation"
cordova-plugin-gyroscope 0.1.4 "Device Gyroscope"
cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard 2.1.2 "cordova-plugin-ionic-keyboard"
cordova-plugin-ionic-webview 2.1.4 "cordova-plugin-ionic-webview"
cordova-plugin-request-location-accuracy 2.2.3 "Request Location Accuracy"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 5.0.2 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.4.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.3 "Whitelist"
cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing 5.4.4 "SocialSharing"
cordova-sqlite-storage 2.6.0 "Cordova sqlite storage plugin"
es6-promise-plugin 4.2.2 "Promise"
```

meu package.json: (https://pastebin.com/dWRUGnqr)

Talvez possa ajudar, qnd instalei o plugin recebi essa mensagem:

```
Saved plugin info for "cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" to config.xml
config file *-Info.plist requested for changes not found at /var/www/html/git/projeto/rodoviasApp/platforms/android/*-Info.plist, ignoring
config file *-Info.plist requested for changes not found at /var/www/html/git/projeto/rodoviasApp/platforms/android/*-Info.plist, ignoring
config file *-Info.plist requested for changes not found at /var/www/html/git/projeto/rodoviasApp/platforms/browser/*-Info.plist, ignoring
config file *-Info.plist requested for changes not found at /var/www/html/git/projeto/rodoviasApp/platforms/browser/*-Info.plist, ignoring
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

eu percebi que é um erro de versão, meu ionic native core é ^4 e o plugin pede a versão 5. arrumei instalando uma versão mais antiga do plugin usando o comando

```
npm install @ionic-native/social-sharing@^4
```

depois disso foi preciso ir até o arquivo config.xml e mudar a seguinte linha:

```
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" >
```

para:

```
   <plugin name="cordova-plugin-x-socialsharing" spec="^4.20.0">
```

ps.no lugar de 4.2 coloque a versão q vc instalou com o npm no passo anterior.